# filter on multiple columns and operation row wise pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if a1_status, b1_status, c1_status, d1_status equal "Active" and a1, b1, c1, d1 equals "Loan" then
output column "Loan_active" contains count of "Active" row wise.
input dataframe looks like this.

[image]

output dataframe :

[image]

use below code to create same dataframe mentioned above in image in pandas .

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':['Loan','Loan','Loan'],
            'a1_status' : ['active','closed','active'] ,
            'b1' : ['Loan','Loan','Loan'],
            'b1_status' : ['active','active','active'] ,
            'c1' : ['Credit','Credit','Credit'],
            'c1_status' : ['closed','closed','closed'] ,
            'd1' : ['Loan','Loan','Loan'],
            'd1_status' : ['closed','closed','active'] ,
})
print(df)
```

Comment: What is the output columns name, `d1_status` or `Loan_acitve` which shows in your desire table ? And the output column in your desire table doesn't fit what you want in your question.  Values in `c1` only contain `Credit`, which doesn't meet the given condition for generating values for the new column.

Comment: if c1 column doesn't contain "Loan" value then i have to ignore that. and "Loan_acitve" is the output column name

Comment: did you attempt to solve it? kindly share your code for the attempt(s)

Answer (score 4):

Let us do `shift`

```
df['new'] = (df.eq('active') & df.shift(axis=1).eq('Loan')).sum(axis=1)
Out[349]: 
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Of course, it assumes that the "loan" column will be just left to "status"  columns, but it can easily be worked around by sorting the columns first.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not as elegant as the other, but it explictly select the columns that includes ONLY loans, then check their status.
But this also assumes that the status columns will be named *loan*_status.

```
loan = df.columns[df.isin(["Loan"]).all()]
df['loan_active'] = df[loan+"_status"].eq('active').sum(axis=1)
```

or if you prefer one liners;

```
df['loan_active'] = df[df.columns[df.isin(["Loan"]).all()]+"_status"].eq('active').sum(axis=1)
```